# Why can weekends cause harmony?

Tags: poisson-distribution, stochastic-processes, poisson-process, fourier-transform

The following plot shows power spectra (periodograms) of a sample from $X_t \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(1)$ along with that same sample where:

- Weekends were set to zero
- Sundays were set to zero
- Saturdays were set to zero

[image]

I suspect this can be explained in terms of Fourier series because we're looking at the square of the Fourier transform. I have a guess that there is some kind of interference pattern, but I'm unsure about how to procedure when the signal is a random variable rather than a deterministic variable. Really these spectra are instances of random spectra when we think about the data being a transformed Poisson process.

Why are there multiple peaks?

---

Requested by mhdadk:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.signal import periodogram

dates = pd.date_range('1970-02-23', '2023-03-20')
weekdays = dates.dayofweek < 5
notsunday = dates.dayofweek != 6
notsaturday = dates.dayofweek != 5
x = np.random.poisson(size=dates.size)
y = x * weekdays
z = x * notsunday
w = x * notsaturday

titles = ['Poisson', 'Weekdays', 'Not Sunday', 'Not Saturday']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(4)
for i, var in enumerate([x,y,z,w]):
    freq, pxx = periodogram(var)
    axes[i].plot(freq, pxx)
    axes[i].set_title(titles[i])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

---

I was reminded by someone to check if the peaks are equally spaced. Indeed, they are! Using the approximate periods of 7, 3.5, and 2.33 from the plots we approximately have

$$\frac{1}{7} - \frac{1}{\frac{7}{2}} = -\frac{1}{7}$$

$$\frac{1}{\frac{7}{2}} - \frac{1}{2.33} \approx -\frac{1}{7}$$

Equally spaced frequencies are sometimes called *harmonics*, which has origins in the study of music. So these are harmonics seem to be reoccur every week week. Why?

Comment: Could you provide code on how you computed the power spectra? If your sampling rate is low, it could be the case some peaks are aliases.

Comment: @mhdadk Interesting idea. I've included the code for this example in the question. Note that the sampling frequency is 1 day, so the highest frequency shown on the spectra is 1/2 day$^{-1}$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency

Comment: You superimposed a periodic signal.  The FT will pick it up: that's what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that these peaks are what are known as *harmonics*. In fact, these peaks all occur at the same frequencies: $\frac{1}{7},\frac{2}{7},\frac{3}{7},$ and so on, albeit with different amplitudes for each of your scenarios of "weekdays", "not Saturday", and "not Sunday". I'll now explain why they appear, in contrast to the spectrum of $X_t$.

First, because $X_t$ is stationary with finite mean and variance, then it is also wide-sense stationary, and so, by the [Wiener–Khinchin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%E2%80%93Khinchin_theorem), its periodogram is an estimate of the Fourier transform of the auto-correlation function (ACF) of $X_t$. That is, if we let $\mathcal F\{X_t\}(f)$ be the Fourier transform of $X_t$ at the frequency $f$ Hz, then the periodogram is approximately $\mathcal F\{E[X_tX_{t+\tau}]\}(f) = \mathcal F\{R_{XX}(\tau)\}(f)$, where $R_{XX}(\tau) = E[X_tX_{t+\tau}]$ is the ACF. Therefore, if we plot the [correlogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlogram#Estimation_of_autocorrelations)  (which is an estimate of the autocorrelation function) of each of the signals that you plotted, then we can gain some insight as to why these peaks appear.

We first start with the correlogram of $X_t$ (I'm assuming that your code was run first):

```py
def correlogram(x):
    grammian = x[...,None] @ x[...,None].T
    acf = np.zeros(grammian.shape[1])
    for i in range(grammian.shape[1]):
        # to compute the value of the acf with lag i, we compute the
        # sample mean for the ith diagonal of the grammian. This is because
        # the acf of wide-sense stationary signal is shift-invariant and only
        # depends on the lag. Note that, because the ith diagonal get smaller
        # as i increases, then we have less samples to compute the mean, and
        # so the estimate is less accurate. This explains the spikes for
        # increasing lags
        acf[i] = np.diagonal(grammian,i).mean()
    lags = np.arange(grammian.shape[1])
    return acf,lags
acf,lags = correlogram(x)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(2,1)
ax[0].plot(lags,acf)
ax[0].set_ylabel(r"ACF($\tau$) for $X_t$")
ax[1].plot(lags,acf)
ax[1].set_xlim([7500,7550])
ax[1].set_xlabel(r"$\tau$")
ax[1].set_ylabel(r"ACF($\tau$) for $X_t$")
```

[image]
As expected, the ACF approximately represents white noise, as $X_t$ is a sequence of independent and identically distributed Poisson random variables with mean $1$. Moreover, in the second axes, we see that the mean is approximately $1$, which makes sense as the ACF should have a mean component equal to $1^2 = 1$, unlike the auto-covariance function. This explains why the periodogram for $X_t$ represents that of white noise.

We now estimate the ACF for all other signals:

```py
acfy,lags = correlogram(y)
acfw,lags = correlogram(w)
acfz,lags = correlogram(z)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(3,2,sharex=False,sharey=False)
ax[0,0].plot(lags,acfy)
ax[0,0].set_ylabel(r"Weekdays")
ax[0,1].stem(lags,acfy)
ax[0,1].set_xlim([7500,7520])

ax[1,0].plot(lags,acfw)
ax[1,0].set_ylabel(r"not Saturday")
ax[1,1].stem(lags,acfw)
ax[1,1].set_xlim([7500,7520])

ax[2,0].plot(lags,acfz)
ax[2,0].set_ylabel(r"not Sunday")
ax[2,0].set_xlabel(r"$\tau$")
ax[2,1].stem(lags,acfz)
ax[2,1].set_xlim([7500,7520])
ax[2,1].set_xlabel(r"$\tau$")
```

[image]
We see that all 3 correlograms have a period of $7$ days. However, their shapes throughout these 7 days, and the amplitude of their correlations, differ. If we compute the Fourier transform of these ACFs, then, because they are all periodic with a period of 7 samples per cycle, then you will see the harmonics at frequencies of $\frac{1}{7},\frac{2}{7},\frac{3}{7},...$ cycles per sample, although each with different amplitudes. Of course, this doesn't explain why harmonics appear in the first place, and not a single peak at $\frac{1}{7}$. For that, I will defer you to [this helpful answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/61912/52433).

---

Here is another perspective:

Let $N$ be the number of days between the dates $1970/02/23$ and $2023/03/20$. Then, for the "Weekdays" scenario, associate the signal of length $N$, $$w[k] = \begin{cases} 1,&\text{if the kth day is a weekday} \\ 0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ Do the same thing for the "Not Saturday" and "Not Sunday" scenarios. The resulting signals are the `weekdays`, `notsaturday`, and `notsunday` variables in your question. Then, for each of these three signals, compute their ACFs and their periodograms (even though they are deterministic). Then, by the [convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem), the periodograms of `y,z,` and `w` will be the convolution of the periodgrams of `weekdays` and `x`, `notsunday` and `x`, and `notsaturday` and `x`.